# Angular 2 Lazy loading causes delay between view change

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading

I have a side menu that can be toggled. Inside that side menu there is an anchor tag that directs the user to the admin page which is a module itself

```
    <a[routerLink]="['/admin']" (click)="sidenav.close()">Admin</a>
```

I am lazy loading it by

```
    { path: 'admin', loadChildren: 'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule' },
```

The small issue I have is, when the user opens up the side nav, clicks on that link for the first time this is what I will see...

1. The side menu closes half way, freezes for 500ms (estimate). At this moment, I still see the old component at the background while the admin module is loaded.
2. Once the module is loaded, the side menu disappears and the admin page is shown. It is quite a bad user experience because the side menu suppose to hide smoothly (Which it does without lazy loading)

I would imagine I need to to change the click function to not close the side nav straight away, but instead, do something like

```
(click)="onAdminLinkClick()"

onAdminLinkClick() {
    // close side nav straight away

    // display loading screen or progress bar  

    // load admin module

    // dismiss loading screen or progress bar once complete loading and show
}
```

So the main question really is if there is a way to detect when the load finishes so I can cancel any loading or close any thing that I need to close

I am not sure how this can be implemented in angular 2. Much appreciated for the help

Comment: You might consider using `preload` https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-preloading-modules-ba3c75e424cb#.edo2miw81, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#custom-preloading

Comment: Thats a nice feature to have. However, as most of my user is not "admin", there is no need for them to preload this data. I am happy for the user to wait for the data to load before navigating. I am finding that the UI freezes completely during the loading period. Is that normal for lazy loading with navigation? Is there a way to avoid it (by making it async or display a loading screen while it loads in background)?

Comment: Sorry, don't know. I haven't tried lazy loading with TS. Might be a browser issue that the browser blocks while loading. How big is the lazy loaded part (from the network tab in the browser console)?

Comment: 150kb for a normal ng server build. quite large yeh? Ps. Using Chrome

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can by using RouterEvent

let say loading is the variable that is true to display any loading icon, so you can do this inside your app.component.ts file

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
        //lazyloading start
        if(event instanceof RouteConfigLoadStart) {
        } 
        //lazy loading end
        else if(event instanceof RouteConfigLoadEnd) {
            this.loading = false;
        }
    })
}
```